# Can not find password protected sharing in Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: c#, windows

I want to copy file with file.copy() command in my c sharp app to the another computer on a local network running on a windows Server 2012R2 which is Domain member server , but first I should Turn off password protected sharing which I can not find.

[image]

where can I find this Option or what should I do instead.

Comment: Despite using the words `with file.copy() command` , this is not a programming question - voting to migrate to SuperUser.

Comment: is there any way that i could do in my c sharp app to solve this problem? @LynnCrumbling

Comment: If you try a manual file copy (using explorer), do you run into the same problem?

Comment: No.I can do everything with my Remote Connection access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. The problem is Solved by enabling Guest account status in local security policy local policies\Security options.